# Insert Query is inserting only first row from the result set in the database table

Tags: java

I am fetching records from table EmployeeLeave and storing it in a result set. Then I am inserting this result set in a database table but I am able to insert only the first row of the result set instead of all the rows.
How can i insert all the rows of the result set?

```
r = stmt.executeQuery("select * from EmployeeLeave where EmployeeNo='"+empno+"'");
while(r.next())
{
    for(int i=0;i<=r.getRow();i++)
    {
        int empid = r.getInt(1);
        String leave = r.getString(2);
        r = stmt.executeQuery("insert into ApprovedLeave values('"+empid+"','"+leave+"','True')");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're learning Java, learn it in the good way and use PreparedStatement instead of Statement. Here are two articles to read: [Why Prepared Statements are important and how to use them "properly"](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365244/Why-Prepared-Statements-are-important-and-how-to-use-them-properly) and [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `executeQuery` while iterating through the `ResultSet` `r`. This will effectively reset your first `ResultSet` as well as your `Statement`, resulting in only one insert being made. To fix, create a new `Statement`.

For inserting `executeUpdate` should be used:

```
stmt2.executeUpdate("insert into ApprovedLeave values('"+empid+"','"+leave+"','True')");
```

Comment: I have tried with different Result Set but it is again inserting only the first row

Comment: AFAIK you will need to create a new statement also.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the inner quert for the first time, it closes the result set from the outer query, because you are re-using the same jdbc statement. For this to work, you'll need to use two different statement object instances.

However, there's really no reason to pull all of that data back to the application, just to send it back to the database. You could just do something like (syntax may vary slightly depending on database vendor):

```
"insert into ApprovedLeave select EmployeeNo, leave, 'True' from EmployeeLeave where EmployeeNo = '" + empno + "'"
```

And even better yet would be a PreparedStatement with:

```
"insert into ApprovedLeave select EmployeeNo, leave, 'True' from EmployeeLeave where EmployeeNo = ?"
```

where you then bind your empno variable to the statement

Answer (score 0):

It may be because r pointing at the last row when you call the second method. Do you need to reset r before the next operation with it?

Comment: It is a valid answer, yet you should put more effort. Read [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862) to get more info, specially from point 8 to 11.